# How to get the current country of the view area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, country

Following part of code delivers me the country where my marker (not draggable) is set …

```
for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++) {
  if (results[0].address_components[i].types[0] == "country") {
     clientPositionMarkerCountry = results[0].address_components[i].long_name;
  }
}
```

When the user moves over an other country (e.g. next to this country or any other) I want to get the current country (or maybe if possible current countries) of the viewarea he is then.

Comment: if someone needs more information just ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?lat=43.797409&lng=27.904508&zoom=6&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/world_countries_kml.xml

Uses [geoxml3](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) to render a KML file.  Detects the country polygons that are visible in the viewport and displays them in the sidebar.

Comment: yeah this is very similar to the solution I am looking for … thank you ;)