# Changing a list of locations upon map resize event

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a bunch of locations in a DB that I want to appear in a list below a Google map with pins for each location.

However I want the list to only consist of those locations found within the borders of the map. So when the map is zoomed in or out the list below it changes to include only locations found within the map borders.

Each location has a latitude and longitude. My best guess is that I need JavaScript to figure out the latitude/longitude of the map corners and then do a SELECT query to find the locations that fall between those parameters.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the current country of the view area?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065235/how-to-get-the-current-country-of-the-view-area/16073913#16073913)

Comment: Seems Geoxml3 does all the heavy work there. I don't think it will help me in my situation ..