# Last visit from.... (JavaScript??)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, geolocation

This is my first question and maybe it's a bit difficult. (well I think so) How can I add a message that says the city and country of the last visit on a website? A message like the one in the attached image.

[Last visiti from...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1kn7.png)

I am going to deepen the subject with a very cool website, where I have seen the location of the last visit to the page. I would love to learn how to do it, but I haven't been able to yet. Please look at the bottom right in... [www.rauno.me](http://www.rauno.me)

I used the Geolocation method: getCurrentPosition() method... But I don't quite like my result.

Comment: Maybe that will help you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16065235/how-to-get-the-current-country-of-the-view-area

Comment: This sounds like a backend thing. Use `.getCurrentPosition()` to get the location, then send it to your backend and do whatever you want with it on the next time you serve the site.

Comment: `But I don't quite like it` - what's wrong with it? Do people refuse to give your website their location? There's nothing you can do about that except maybe try IP geolocation, which is about as accurate as blindly throwing a dart on a map

Comment: I am going to deepen the subject with a very cool website, where I have seen the location of the last visit to the page. I would love to learn how to do it, but I haven't been able to yet. 
Please look at the bottom right in... 
https://rauno.me/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have a backend to save the last visit location and for each time someone visit your page you will update the value to their current location.

Comment: Hi there Daniel!
You're probably right. Do you know how to do it or where I can find a way to do it?. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't find a tutorial, but I can give you some steps. 

- Create a simple API server using any language/framework and a table to save the latitude and longitude 
- Create two endpoints: one for update the table with the newest lat/long and another one to get these values 
- On your frontend call the endpoint to update the table each time an user visit your site 
- On your frontend you will need to use an API to convert the lat/long in the city/country (there's an API on google called [geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding?hl=en)